# How to show relationships between Todo-lists?

Tags: xml, bash, devtools

How can I show relations between ToDo-lists? I am using Devtodo.

I will give an example. I have my MIT humor in one XML-file:

> ```
>  <todo version="0.1.19">
>      <note priority="low" time="1237320287">
>          see the MIT humor-video
>      </note> 
>  </todo>
> ```

Other file is about Usenet-humor

> ```
>  <todo version="0.1.19">
>      <note priority="verylow" time="1237321441">
>          read about Usenet Humor
>      </note> 
>  </todo>
> ```

When I change one of my humor-file, I would like to have an alert that shows me my other Todo-lists that have a word "humor" in the title.

**Partial Solution**

I tried to add a property to the cd-command in my .bashrc that keep showing me my main Todo-lists:

> alias='ls (); find /* -name mainlist'

but I feel I am doing the job in a hard way. How are you managing your Todo-lists between folders? Have you got a lot of scripts to show relationships between Todo-lists?

Comment: If you want to test Devtodo, please have a look at here: http://swapoff.org/wiki/DevTodo.

Comment: I don't really get it. You want to be warned (how ?) when some xml-todo-files are modified ? Precise your question, please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would  markup some words as keys say with a '`<topic>humor</topic>` tag then write some thing that would search through the todos to find the related ones   .
but I'm thinking that the topics would be fewer. So just keep an index by topic of all open todos with those topics in your app, not in the XML.